# Join 3 Tables with disparate counts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables:

- WellnessProviders
- WellnessVisits
- WellnessReferrals

Which look like this (sample):

```
| ProviderName | ProviderEmail   |
|--------------|-----------------|
| Steve        | steve@steve.com |
| Jeff         | jeff@jeff.com   |
```

And:

```
| ReferralNumber | AssignedToEmail |
|----------------|-----------------|
| 1              | steve@steve.com |
| 2              | jeff@jeff.com   |
| 3              | jeff@jeff.com   |
```

And:

```
| VisitNumber | CheckOutProviderEmail |
|-------------|-----------------------|
| 1           | steve@steve.com       |
| 2           | steve@steve.com       |
```

We are trying to create a query that counts the total referrals by provider AND the total visits by provider. If I write the queries separately, things work as expected:

```
SELECT wp.ProviderName, count(wr.AssignedToEmail)
FROM dbo.WellnessProviders wp
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessReferrals wr ON wp.ProviderEmail=wr.AssignedToEmail
GROUP BY wp.ProviderName
```

Returns all providers by name and a count of all referrals.

```
SELECT wp.ProviderName, count(wv.CheckInProviderEmail)
FROM dbo.WellnessProviders wp
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessVisits wv ON wp.ProviderEmail=wv.CheckOutProviderEmail
GROUP BY wp.ProviderName;
```

Returns all providers by name and a count of all visits. I am trying to combine the two sets so we get the provider's name, the count of referrals, and the count of visits. I tried  to do this by writing

```
SELECT wp.ProviderName, count(wr.AssignedToEmail), count(wv.CheckOutProviderEmail)
FROM dbo.WellnessProviders wp
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessReferrals wr
    ON wp.ProviderEmail=wr.AssignedToEmail
LEFT JOIN dbo.WellnessVisits wv
    ON wv.CheckOutProviderEmail=wp.ProviderEmail
GROUP BY wp.ProviderName;
```

And while that produced all of the providers, the counts were all wrong. I need help joining the first two queries into a single table.

The desired result would be this:

```
| ProviderName | Total Referrals | Total Check-Outs |
|--------------|-----------------|------------------|
| Jeff         | 2               | 0                |
| Steve        | 1               | 2                |
```

Comment: Counting two unrelated joins in the same query is not going to be easier than querying them separately

Comment: Perhaps not - we are trying to create a unified dashboard to provide statistics on our providers. We had hoped having a unique field (email) between the tables would facilitate the join.

Comment: You can certainly join them, but whether its meaningful is another question.

Comment: join "derived tables" i.e. you cab get a single query, but that query runs subqueries so that the counts are accurate. You cannot (reliably) do both otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL joins multiply the number of rows, so if attempting to count (or any aggregation) you always run the risk of the aggregates being incorrect when performed over joins, especially over multiple joins. The simple solution to this is to do the aggregations as subqueries and join those together into a single query e.g:

```
SELECT
      wp.ProviderName
    , wr.count_assigned
    , wv.count_visits
FROM dbo.WellnessProviders wp
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          AssignedToEmail
        , count(*) count_assigned
    FROM dbo.WellnessReferrals
    GROUP BY AssignedToEmail
    ) wr ON wp.ProviderEmail = wr.AssignedToEmail
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          CheckOutProviderEmail
        , count(*) AS count_visits
    FROM dbo.WellnessVisits
    GROUP BY CheckOutProviderEmail
    ) wv ON wv.CheckOutProviderEmail = wp.ProviderEmail
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked word for word. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as:

```
SELECT ProviderName,
       COUNT(DISTINCT wr.AssignedToEmail) AS TotalReferrals,
       COUNT(DISTINCT wv.CheckOutProviderEmail) AS TotalCheckOuts
FROM WellnessProviders wp
LEFT JOIN WellnessReferrals wr ON wp.ProviderEmail = wr.AssignedToEmail
LEFT JOIN WellnessVisits wv ON wp.ProviderEmail = wv.CheckOutProviderEmail
GROUP BY ProviderName;
```

I have used here distinct keyword to ensure each referral and visit is counted once.

I hope this will help you!!